# Python executable that requests a directory

Tags: python, pandas

I don't have any experience with python beyond this current project I'm working on. I'm trying to turn my code into an executable to "automate" most of the data processing on .dat files that are placed into a new folder per new experiment.

Is it possible to have a python .exe request the directory you want it to perform the code on?

I'm working in pandas btw, if it matters.

Comment: Hello! could you please like explain more details, for example on this statement `Is it possible to have a python .exe request the directory you want it to perform the code on?` Like you can provide an example source code Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very detailed. I can add images of my code at some point, but for instance, my current code creates a directory to a specific folder full of .dat files filled with raw data. I turn these into dataframes, perform some filtering, formulas, and arithmetic on specific columns of these dataframes. I do these same repetitive actions to raw data weekly, but the raw data is stored into different folders from one day to the next. So I would like to have my code be an executable that I do not have to reopen, change the directory, and save in order to run again.